# Inverse Galois Problem: the two-fold central extension of $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2) \cong [W(E_7),W(E_7)]$

Tags: galois-theory, simple-groups, galois-representations, galois-extensions, weyl-group

I came across the following problem when I was trying to construct a certain type of homomorphisms from $\Gamma_{\mathbb Q}$ to $E^{sc}_7(\mathbb F_p)$ for any prime $p$:

**Is the *double cover* of $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)(=PSp_6(\mathbb F_2))$ known as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$?**

A little background about $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$: It is a finite simple group of order $2^9\cdot 3^4 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ with Schur multiplier 2 (sometimes denoted by $C_3(2)$). So it possesses a unique non-trivial two-fold central extension which I shall denote by $\widetilde{Sp}_6(\mathbb F_2)$. It is a quasisimple group. On the other hand, $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$ is isomorphic to the derived subgroup of the Weyl group of type $E_7$ (denoted by $W=W(E_7)$), which is isomorphic to $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)\times \{\pm 1\}$. It follows that $\widetilde{Sp}_6(\mathbb F_2)$ can be realized as the pullback of $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2) \cong [W,W] \to SO(7)$ along the projection $Spin(7) \to SO(7)$. Let $G=E_7^{sc}$ be the simply-connected Chevalley group of type $E_7$. Let $T$ be a maximal torus of 
$G$. Consider the following exact sequence:
$$1\to T \to N_G(T) \to N_G(T)/T\cong W \to 1$$
By a result of J.Adam and X.He, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00510.pdf, the sequence does not split. Moreover, by going along their line of argument, it is not hard to see that the sequence does not split for $[W,W]\cong Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$ either. I hope to build a homomorphism $\Gamma_{\mathbb Q} \to E_7^{sc}(\mathbb C)$ whose image is isomorphic to the inverse image of $W$ in $N_G(T)$. This problem can be easily reduced to the problem of realizing $\widetilde{Sp}_6(\mathbb F_2)$ as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$.

It is known that the Weyl group of a reductive group $G$ can be realized a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$: the idea is that the Galois group of
the characteristic polynomial of $Ad(g)|_{\mathfrak g}$ for "generic" $g\in G(\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to the Weyl group of $G$, provided that $G/\mathbb Q$ is split. This dates back to E.Cartan's famous thesis 120 years ago! See Joulve,Kowalski and Zywina's paper https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/weyl-group-e8.pdf for a good account of this story. 
In particular, the finite simple group $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$ can be realized as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ (being a direct summand of $W(E_7)$). To attack $\widetilde{Sp}_6(\mathbb F_2)$, it is natural to consider the embedding problem posed by the non-split exact sequence:
$$1 \to \{\pm 1\} \to \widetilde{Sp}_6(\mathbb F_2) \to Sp_6(\mathbb F_2) \to 1$$ I don't know how to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated. On the other hand, since this group is a concrete group with generators and relations, I wonder if one can find a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ that realizes it using computer algorithms.

Comment: If I were you I would post this question on MathOverflow. This is a delightful question (that I don't know the answer to) and all that is going to happen is no one is going to notice it in the deluge of chain rule questions.

Comment: Oh yeah, I will do. Thanks!

Comment: If you post this in MathOverflow please crosslink the two editions. @Ravi should not have forgotten to emphasize that as a rule we disprove of having the same question repeated in two places. I do sincerely hope that you get replies for the question is a good one (+1 from  me). Unfortunately inverse Galois theory is not my forte, but we do have more knowledgeable users!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My apologies. My only excuse is that the question got me so excited that I forgot all etiquette. I'll be more aware next time.

Comment: Not much harm done @Ravi. And I agree with you. If we had more questions like this less calculus homework, the site would be that much better.